GitLab, IntelliJ and MacBook: Incorrect credentials. Request response: Bad credentials
I am trying to connect IntelliJ to a GitLab account on a Macbook.
I follow these steps:

go to Settings then **GitHub** then +
Then filling Server and token


For the server field, it's defaulted to github.com and cannot be changed
For the token, I use the access token generated in Gitlab

But I get the following error:

Incorrect credentials. Request response: Bad credentials

I also tried to follow the following steps:

Settings then **GitLab** then +
Then filling Server and token


For the server field, I use the <gitlab repo url>
For the token, I use the access token generated in GitLab

But, again, I get the following error message:

Login failed. Check API token or GitLab version. Log in via Git if the
version is older than 14.0

I don't know what to do now, please advice. Thank you

I don't understand. In one sentence you say that you get an error about incorrect credentials and in the next sentence you say that it works perfectly.

@mkrieger1 : the steps works fine when using the access token of github. But, following the same step, it doesn't work when using gitlab token.

Then you should remove the part where you say that you get an error "Incorrect credentials" when using the GitHub token to access GitHub.

@mkrieger1: hope it is clear now

Yes, although I think it should be obvious that using Gitlab credentials to log in to GitHub won't work.

mkrieger1: I followed couple of tutorials, and just like you, I was skeptical at first. But then they all say it is a "Git" thing and IntelliJ will figure out it is a gitlab access-token from the token itself. Anyway, it doesn't work as well as using the GitLab option.
